# Wordpress theme scrolling page issue

Tags: wordpress

First of all, the disclaimer: I am an absolute newbie.

I am modifying [this](http://minimable.fedeweb.net/demo/) theme, and, so far, I've come up with [this](http://www.fantastificio.comuf.com/wordpress).

My problem is the scrolling effect (amongst other things): when one clicks on one of the links in the circles, the scrolling effect will stop too 'early', as if the anchor were set too 'high' in relation to the text, leaving lots of white space above it.

I could try to set another anchor, perhaps a single character of the same colour of the background next to the h1 of every section, but I fear I might lose the scrolling effect. Also, I don't really know how to do that in WP.

So, in substance, my question is: how do I set the page to scroll so that the heading of each page is closer to the top of the screen?

Not sure if this of any use, but the following is the content of the template-home.php file, relating to navigation:

```
<div class="row">
        <nav class="<?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fw_label_four', true)) { ?> offset2 <?php } else {?>offset3 <?php } ?> span8" id="nav-home">
            <ul class="row">
                <li class="span2">
                    <a class="circle-menu circle-black" href="#page-2"><span class="label-link"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fw_label_one', true);?></span></a>
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                </li>
                <li class="span2">
                    <a class="circle-menu" href="#page-3"><span class="label-link"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fw_label_two', true);?></span></a>
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                </li>
                <li class="span2">
                    <a class="circle-menu circle-black" href="#page-4"><span class="label-link"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fw_label_three', true);?></span></a>
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                </li>
                <?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fw_label_four', true)) { ?>
                <li class="span2">
                    <a class="circle-menu" href="#page-5"><span class="label-link"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fw_label_four', true);?></span></a>
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: Change in css section class padding-top : 120 to 90 try it

Comment: Thank you very much, kruti. It made very little difference, and I had to lower it to 15. The issue is still not solved, by the way.

Comment: I can't load your site. can you send me your code ?